# libgdx firing event from actor to call another actor

Tags: android, libgdx, event-handling

I'm using `Scene2D` and have 2 actors. When `MyActor1` is touched, it should fire an event which should be handled by `MyActor2`. I've tried several different variants on how to fire and even from `MyActor1`, but it is still not being handled by `MyActor2`. The full code is below.

Game class which just forwards to a Screen

```
public class MyGdxGame extends Game {
   @Override
   public void create() {
       setScreen(new MyGdxScreen());
   }
}
```

Screen class (empty methods ommited)

```
public class MyGdxScreen implements Screen {

   private Stage stage;

   @Override
   public void show() {
       stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());
       stage.addActor(new MyActor1());
       stage.addActor(new MyActor2());
       Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
   }

   @Override
   public void render(float delta) {
       Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
       Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

       stage.act(delta);
       stage.draw();
   }

   @Override
   public void dispose() {
       stage.dispose();
   }
}
```

First Actor (fires custom event when touched)

```
public class MyActor1 extends Actor {

   private Texture image;

   public MyActor1() {
       this.image = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");

       setPosition(0, 0);
       setBounds(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
       setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

       addListener(new InputListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
               Gdx.app.log("touched", "First actor touched!");
               MyActor1.this.fire(new ActorTouchedListener.ActorTouchedEvent());
               MyActor1.this.getParent().fire(new ActorTouchedListener.ActorTouchedEvent());
               return true;
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
       batch.draw(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
   }
}
```

Second Actor (should handle an Event fired by Actor1)

```
public class MyActor2 extends Actor {

   public MyActor2() {
       addListener(new ActorTouchedListener());
   }
}
```

Event listener

```
public class ActorTouchedListener implements EventListener {
   @Override
   public boolean handle(Event event) {
       if (event instanceof ActorTouchedEvent) {
           Gdx.app.log("fired", "Second actor got event!");
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }

public static class ActorTouchedEvent extends Event {
     public ActorTouchedEvent() {
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect from this two lines? `MyActor1.this.fire(new ActorTouchedListener.ActorTouchedEvent());
               MyActor1.this.getParent().fire(new ActorTouchedListener.ActorTouchedEvent());`

Comment: @icarumbas I tried both those lines and both didn't work for me. I would like to know how to properly fire an event from one actor which then can be handled by another actor within the same stage.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines do nothing.

```
MyActor1.this.fire(new ActorTouchedListener.ActorTouchedEvent()); 
MyActor1.this.getParent().fire(new ActorTouchedListener.ActorTouchedEvent());
```

To call `Actor` from another Actor you should create instance of it.

```
public class MyActor1 extends Actor {

   private Texture image;
   private Actor actor2; // instance of MyActor2

   public MyActor1(actor2: Actor) { 
       this.image = new Texture("badlogic.jpg");
       this.actor2 = actor2;     

       setPosition(0, 0);
       setBounds(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
       setTouchable(Touchable.enabled);

       addListener(new InputListener() {
           @Override
           public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
               Gdx.app.log("touched", "First actor touched!");
               actor2.fire(event);  // Here we fire event on MyActor2
               return true;
           }
       });
   }

   @Override
   public void draw(Batch batch, float parentAlpha) {
       batch.draw(image, 0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
   }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but then every actor should know whom to notify. Then we don't really use events and listeners as long as we do the call directly. I was looking for something similar to Observer pattern.

Comment: @OleksandrShmatko so why you want Actor to notify other Actors? Stage does that.

Comment: Main reason is that I want to make it (the notification) asynchronous. The whole flow which I'm trying to achieve is - 1) when actor is touched, it should redraw it's image 2) then another actor should be notified to redraw it's image 3) there should be an artificial delay (for example, 1 second) between first actor image redraw and second actor image redraw.
With synchronous call the delay appears before the actors being redrawn, not in-between.

Comment: @OleksandrShmatko LibGDX's event system is not an observer pattern messaging system. Events only fire upward toward ancestors. It's really only intended for input processing.

Comment: @Tenfour04 then how to achieve following flow: `MyActor1` is touched -> it gets redrawn -> delay of 1 second occurs -> `MyActor2` gets redrawn? If I use `Thread.sleep(1_000L)` after firing an event, both actors would be redrawn at the same time with initial delay of 1 second.

Comment: Use Actions for this. Create a custom Action that calls your redraw method on your actor subclass. When one of your actors is clicked, redraw it, then call otherActor.addAction(Actions.sequence(Actions.delay(1), Actions.action(MyAction.class)));

Comment: Never sleep the render thread, by the way. That's the same as pausing your entire game for the sleep time.

Answer (score 0):

#### Intercomponent events

LibGDX does not provide embeded *intercomponent* event system, but you can use additional frameworks. For example [LibGDX Autumn](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/tree/master/autumn#libgdx-autumn). You can use two type events:

- [text event](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/blob/master/examples/gdx-autumn-tests/core/src/com/github/czyzby/context/event/MyMessageHandler.java) - to notify components about changing of some state
- [object event](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/blob/master/examples/gdx-autumn-tests/core/src/com/github/czyzby/context/event/MyEventHandler.java) - this mechanism deliver your event object to observers

This framework have documentaion and [examples](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/tree/master/examples/gdx-autumn-tests), it will help to do what you want

#### Delayed actor update

For actor's update purposes LibGDX have [actions mechanism](https://github.com/czyzby/gdx-lml/tree/master/examples/gdx-autumn-tests). In your case I suggest to attach `DelayAction` to `MyActor2` with wrapped `MyRedrawAction`

```
DelayAction delayAction = new DelayAction();

// set wrapped action dellay (in sec.)
delayAction.setDuration(1F);
// set wrapped action. It will be invoked after 1 sec. of stage drawing
delayAction.setAction(new MyRedrawAction());

actor2.addAction(delayAction);
```

You can do this in `touchDown()` method as [@icarumbas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7717409/icarumbas) suggest